# What exactly does the pop filter in google photo editor do and how can it be applied to videos?

Tags: photos, google-photos

The google photo editor has a "pop" filter (it might be called diferentlly on an english phone)

I would like to know what exactly this filter does and how it could be applied to a video - for example using adobe after effects or a free tool.

[image: image showing google photo editor while applying a pop filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pop* filter is used to increase sharpness ( though I can't find official description)

For videos, [Adobe Premier Clip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.premiereclip) does similar job using the *highlights* function, accessible from highlighted icon in the first screen shot. Subsequent screenshots show the effect

I am not familiar with Adobe after effects, as Adobe Premier let's me edit on the mobile itself and hence is preferred

[image]
[image]
[image]